# Уровень изоляции транзакций и Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm, jpa

**Первый вопрос**. Какая связь существует между уровнем изоляции транзакций, параметрами JPA `Lock.READ / Lock.WRITE` и версиями `@Version` (Оптимистическая блокировка)? Я более менее понял по отдельности каждую из этих 3 разделов, но не понимаю, как они связаны между собой.  Выбранный уровень изоляции транзакций дает некие «гарантии» при проведении операций с таблицами.  Параметры `Lock.READ/Lock.WRITE` позволяют добиться блокировки полей таблицы при проведении операций. Если я правильно понял, для этого как раз и используются поле `@Version`.  Но все таки не до конца улавливаю связь между эти тремя понятиями. Или они дополняют друг друга, или это разные способы решения одних и тех же проблем. В общем, буду очень благодарен за ответ или же ссылку, где можно прочесть информацию именно по вопросы связи между этими понятиями и их совместном использовании.

**Второй вопрос**. Каким способом в Hibernate можно указать требуемый уровень изоляции транзакции для конкретной транзакции? И принято ли так делать?

Спасибо.

Comment: Хороший вопрос, отвечу чуть позже :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Попробую ответить по порядку:

**Как соотносятся `Lock` и уровни изоляции**

1. Уровень изоляции транзакций (*transaction isolation level*) - относится к чтению данных, но не к записи данных;
2. `Lock` относится к доступу к данным (то есть затрагивает и чтение и запись и модификацию);
3. Можно сказать так, что механизм `Lock` обеспечивает работоспособность различных уровней изоляции данных, в самом тупом примере: если у вас стоит уровень изоляции `READ_COMMITTED`, то вставка произведенная параллельной сессией будет локирована на запись пока сессия не выдаст `commit()`, но лок на чтение будет открыт сразу при запросе вашего `select`, а при `REPEATABLE_READ` оба лока (на чтение и запись) будут стоять до `commit()` - соответственно ваш `select` увидит результаты модификации только после коммита.

**Каким способом в Hibernate можно указать требуемый уровень изоляции транзакции для конкретной транзакции?**

Вообще это не сильно здорово. Уровень изоляции транзакций это принадлежность коннекта к БД, соответственно фактически изменение уровня изоляции равносильно переконнекту к БД, а насколько это дорогая операция вы сами можете оценить исходя из имеющейся у вас ситуации.

Тем не менее, если вы таки решили менять перед каждой транзакцией уровень изоляции транзакций, то самый простой способ это отправить в СУБД *raw SQL query* (любой ORM это поддерживает), типа:

```
ALTER SESSION SET ISOLATION_LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

Некоторую информацию по данному вопросу можно почерпнуть из [статьи с хабра](http://habrahabr.ru/post/271115/)

UPD по второму вопросу:
Аннотация `@Transactional` указывает, что метод должен выполняться в транзакции. Менеджер транзакций открывает новую транзакцию и создаёт для неё экземпляр `Session`, который доступен через `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`. Все методы, которые вызываются в методе с данной аннотацией, также имеют доступ к этой транзакции, потому что экземпляр Session является переменной потока (`ThreadLocal`). Вызов `sessionFactory.openSession()` откроет совсем другую сессию, которая не связана с транзакцией.

Параметр `rollbackFor` указывает исключения, при выбросе которых должен быть произведён откат транзакции. Есть обратный параметр — `noRollbackFor`, указывающий, что все исключения, кроме перечисленных, приводят к откату транзакции.

Параметр `propagation` самый интересный. Он указывает принцип распространения транзакции. Может принимать любое значение из перечисления `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation`.

- `Propagation.REQUIRED` — выполняться в существующей транзакции, если
  она есть, иначе создавать новую.
- `Propagation.MANDATORY` — выполняться
  в существующей транзакции, если она есть, иначе генерировать
  исключение.
- `Propagation.SUPPORTS` — выполняться в существующей
  транзакции, если она есть, иначе выполняться вне транзакции.
- `Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED` — всегда выполняться вне транзакции. Если
  есть существующая, то она будет остановлена.
- `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` — всегда выполняться в новой независимой
  транзакции. Если есть существующая, то она будет остановлена до
  окончания выполнения новой    транзакции.
- `Propagation.NESTED` — если есть текущая транзакция, выполняться в новой, так называемой,
  вложенной транзакции. Если вложенная транзакция будет отменена, то
  это не повлияет на внешнюю транзакцию; если будет отменена внешняя
  транзакция, то будет отменена и вложенная. Если текущей транзакции
  нет, то просто создаётся новая.
- `Propagation.NEVER` — всегда выполнять
  вне транзакции, при наличии    существующей генерировать исключение.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос лёгкий, но ответ слишком длинный. Лучше книжки почитать.

Уровни изоляции, блокировки настоящие и оптимистические - работают каждый над своей проблемой. Прямо они не связаны. Подбирая их комбинацию, получаете то, что Вам нужно.

В jpa предусмотрены как оптимистичные режимы блокировки (полностью полагаются на  @Version), так и пессимистичные (которые выполняются сервером базы данных):

OPTIMISTIC (он же READ)
OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT (он же WRITE)
PESSIMISTIC_READ
PESSIMISTIC_WRITE
PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT

Как изменить уровень изоляции.
Если управляете транзакцией самостоятельно, то и меняйте как хотите (сonnection.setTransactionIsolation? Нужно только connection извлечь из entity из managera). А например JTA изменить вряд ли получится. Там уровень задаётся в конфигурации datasource и изменение его не предполагается. Кажется именно так. Хотя можете уточнить этот момент. Всё течёт, всё изменяется. Может это уже не так.